# Recalculate sum of all select values on change

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249757/jquery-sum-values-from-different-divs-with-same-classes)'s answer in to my code, but I'm hitting issues with the recalculation.

I have three dynamically-created `<select>` dropdowns that hold values from 0 to 25. I have given these a `.select-control` class so that I can access them easier. Code for each is as follows:

```
<select name="amount_1" class="form-control select-control" required>
    <option disabled selected value="">No. of Vouchers</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    ...
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

The other two `<selects>` are named `amount_2` and `amount_3` respectively.

When one of their values changes, I need to recalculate the total sum of the selected options. This is my (non-working) code as it stands now. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
var total = 0;
$(".select-control").change(function() {
    $(".select-control").each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.value);
    });
    alert(total);
});
```

The alert is only for testing purposes. Once working, I will simply update a `<span>` element with the total.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c4fxpa5/).

**EDIT:** After answers, here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c4fxpa5/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your other select option do not have perfect integer value. which results `parseInt(this.value)` to NAN for those select elements. also declare var total in change event as it needs to be reset on change of select elements:

```
$(".select-control").change(function() {
 var total = 0;
  $(".select-control").each(function() {
      total += parseInt(this.value)||0;
  });
  alert(total);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77sho7b0/)**

Answer (score 0):

use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var total=0;
    $(".select-control").change(function() {
        $(".select-control").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        alert(total);
    });
```

Comment: My alert still simply says `NaN`.

Comment: to get val you can simply use `$(this).val()`. also initialize total to 0.

Comment: but some time $(this).val() not gives the value but thanks @MilindAnantwar

Comment: `total` should be inside `change` event handler, otherwise it will calculate wrong value by adding new values to previously calculated total

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 //bind change event for select box
 $(".select-control").change(function() {

    var total = parseInt($(this).val());

    $(".select-control").not(this).each(function() {
        if(parseInt($(this).val()))
        {
          total += parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
    alert(total);
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/qjgk8m9k/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".select-control").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".select-control").each(function() {
           var value = Number($(this).val());
           total += value;
        });
        alert(total);
    });
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/7LvLru4L/