# How can I get sum of values from different divs with the same class using only javascript without libraries?

Tags: javascript

```
let sum = [];
for(i=1; i< 16; i++ ) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(`number${i}`).forEach(function() {
        sum += parseFloat(this.innerText()); 
    });
}
```

I have built a dynamic flexbox table which has students names and their marks in each for every day. there are 15 students as you can guess. Now what I am trying to do is to calculate the sum of all the marks across each row upon clicking update button. I have assigned number1, ... number15 classes for cells in the same row(number1 first row number2 second row, etc). So far I have managed to do this but it does not work. Remember I don't want to use jquery, this needs to be done with javascript only.Any help would be appreciated.(I have an add button which creates a new day onclick with the same classes, so number1, number2 classes  represent arrays of divs with marks as textnodes.)

Comment: `let sum = 0` instead of an array

Comment: yeah but i need the sum for all rows it will be overwritten if I declare sum as variable and I will only be left with the sum of the last row in the best case....

Comment: I want to save the sums of all raws, that's the problem

Comment: Thats not how `+=` works.  If you were using `=` instead, you would be correct, but `+=` takes the current `sum` and adds whatever is on the right of the operator.

Comment: still that's not what i want i want to save the sum of all rows separately. not the overall sum of all rows

Comment: what i want to do is to build an array with length 15 where each element represents the sum of the marks in each row but i dont know how to do it. this line of code doesn't work

Comment: Oh. Then use ‘sum.push(parseFloat(this.innerText()));’

Comment: I get an error  saying document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: My question is identical to this one. I just need to do it with javascript only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249757/sum-of-values-from-different-divs-with-the-same-class

Comment: Editing your post and adding the code with HTML in as a snippet would be helpful.

Comment: im confused, is this the kind of structure you are working with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zdo01es/), do you need to sum every student grades for every one of them?

Comment: yeah exactly for every 15 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to initialize an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) from the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) by using the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) static method, if you want access to the array methods in ECMAScript. Then you can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the sum from each class name, and [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it into the `sum` array:

```
const sum = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  const innerSum = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByClassName(`number${i}`)
  ).reduce(
    (acc, el) => acc + parseFloat(el.innerText),
    0
  );

  sum.push(innerSum);
}
```

Comment: I still get that  el.innerText is not a function

Comment: @goga my bad, that was an error leftover from your code.

Comment: there is a tiny problem left. I have put this in addlistener of update button and when I hit button this message comes up Identifier 'sum' has already been declared. How do I solve this so that upon hitting button every time sum is refreshed and gets new meanings. Table is dynamic and I put values in each cell with prompt.

Comment: @goga you haven't shared the relevant code in your question, so it's not within the scope of my answer, but based on your description, your event listener function has already declared a variable `sum` in the same scope. Please click on the line number in your error code when using the debugger and it will show you where to fix the error.

Comment: still new values don't get added to the members of array when I execute the event. What could be the solution?

Comment: You either need to revise your question with more code or consider asking a new question if you think this is a different problem.

Comment: no the question is the same but it only works with tables whose values are already set and don;t change but in my table upon clicking cells prompt appears and i enter values and the textnodes get changed accordingly then i have update table button. I have created eventlistener function insidie it and put this code in it. I thought when I clicked the update button the members of the array would change. For example if in the first row I had only 1 and zeros If I put 5 instead of 1 I would get 5 as the first member of the array but it doesn' work and I don;t understand why

Comment: That sounds like a lot of details that aren't reflected in the code you've provided. Please update your question to include relevant code as I suggested.

Comment: to put it more simply I have a table where I dynamically add and remove student marks, add days, remove days. And I want to create new array sum [] every time I hit UPDATE TABLE button

Comment: Could you tell me what acc and el variables stand for here?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding a variable within the loop. This will reset for each student, sum their grades, then add it to your sum array:

```
let sum = [];
for(i=1; i< 16; i++ ) {
    let studentSum = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll(`.number${i}`).forEach(function(ele) {
        studentSum += parseFloat(ele.innerText()); 
    });
    sum.push(studentSum)
}
```

**Edit:**

As noted, you can't use document.getElementsByClassName(..).forEach try document.querySelectorAll(..).forEach instead.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function` On top of that, `this` will not refer to each element inside the callback, since `forEach()` does not bind the context of the function.

Comment: yeah exactly it is not a function. that's the problem

Comment: it is html collection and seems that forEach doesn't recognise it as an array

Comment: The W3C specification which defines the `HTMLCollection` class, does not implement the `forEach()` method. The current draft _does_ implement `forEach()` on `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll()`, but I still don't think that's a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you asked for but try to see if that works for you:

```js
const sum = [];
const students = document.querySelectorAll('.student');

for(student of students) {
        sum.push(parseFloat(student.innerText));             
}
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div class="student">1</div>
<div class="student">2</div>
<div class="student">3</div>
```

Comment: Not quite the same as what the OP explained they were trying to do. See my answer, I'm pretty sure it's correct.