# sum of values from inputs or strings from paragraphs with same class names always shows '0'

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, classname

I have a simple shopping cart div in which i have ul list of choosen products. I want to show a sum of price of all products but cant figure it out (li's are created dynamically and can be deleted from the cart so sum should work dynamically too).

This is how the structure of ul looks like:

```
<ul id='koszyk'>
 <li>
   <input type='hidden' class='price' value='20'>
   <p class='p_price'>20 zł</p>
   <...>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to sum by paragraph string using this [Sum of values from different divs with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249757/sum-of-values-from-different-divs-with-the-same-class) , but console output always shows '0':

```
var sum = 0;
$('.p_price').each(function(){
   sum += parseFloat($(this).text());                                    
});
console.log(sum);
```

Script is inside ul. I have also tried this, but with same result:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.price').each(function(){
   sum += parseFloat($(this).valueOf());                                    
});
console.log(sum);
```

I also tried to use array to store all prices but im not good at operating with arrays.
It might be a matter of some simple mistake since im still a beginner so i also prefer a solution as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `val()` method instead of `valueOf()` to obtain the `value` of an input element.

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.price').each(function(){
   sum += parseFloat($(this).val());                                    
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='koszyk'>
 <li>
   <input type='hidden' class='price' value='20'>
   <p class='p_price'>20 zł</p>
   <...>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried with val instead of valueOf but it still shows '0', i also tried to make a path like $('li > .price') but still dont work

Comment: Are you sure the code in the `each` is being executed? Try debugging it or add a console.log statement in there to verify the code is run. It might be that you run the script before the page is loaded and hence no HTML elements can be found, resulting in a sum of 0. If you run the snippet above, you can see the output correctly states 20

Comment: I put console log inside function and it doesnt show up so i guess it's not executed as you said but i dont really know where should i put the script so it will work. Script is inside ul but there are also some other functions i use. I tried to put it outside ul but with same result.

Comment: Try adding the script tag right before the closing tag of the body (`</body>`)

Comment: Okay i figured it out. Li's where "price" inputs are, are created dynamically after pushing button so they arent on the page right when its opened. I had to use DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved event like this $("#koszyk").bind("DOMNodeInserted","DOMNodeRemoved",function(){} so it runs code when li's append inside ul or when they are removed.

Comment: Great, glad you found the issue. Good luck with the rest!